# Payday 2 Scarface mansion, Ernesto Sosa sniped

Tags: payday-2

I was attempting to stealth the mission and was successful till the phone call was made, however before we managed to enter the room where Ernesto Sosa is in(killed him when objective is to Enter the office), one of the crew used a sniper rifle and shot into the room where he is suppose to be in and luckily hit him, I thought we'd clear the mission from there but by the time we enter his room, the mission requires to kill him even though he is dead.

My team tried to go loud by attacking the remaining guards but the objective stays as `Kill Ernesto Sosa` until we were overran.

Is there anyway to continue the mission from there?

Comment: This sounds like a glitch. especially if you killed him but its still asking you to kill him. Maybe report this to the developer?

Comment: I guess so too, but I am hoping like there might be a way to trigger another alternative mission/complete it so if I meet similar situation I will not have to break my crime spree